# Vue How to add phone number call link

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

In my `vuejs`-application, I have a table with some users which also includes a phone number. Now I want to make the phone number clickable, but for some reason it does not work.

This is what I got:

```
<router-link class="table-row" tag="div" v-for="entry in paginate(filteredData)" :key="entry.id" :to="routePath + entry.id">
   <div class="table-data" v-for="column in columns" v-bind:key="column.id" :class="column.key">
      <div v-if="column.key == 'phone'" :class="column.key">
         <span>
             <a href="tel:'`${entry[column.key]}`">{{entry[column.key]}}</a>
         </span>
      </div>
      <div v-else> 
        <span>{{entry[column.key]}}</span>
      </div>
   </div>
</router-link>
```

the result is `<a href="/users/18/details">12448877</a>` - which is the same route as the `<router-link>` - how can I achieve that the phone number gets displayed without using any plugin/package?

Comment: Have you tried console logging `${entry[column.key]}` to see if it has a value?

Answer (score 2):

I think this line should be

```
<a href="tel:'`${entry[column.key]}`">{{entry[column.key]}}</a>
```

like

```
<a :href="`tel:${entry[column.key]}`">{{entry[column.key]}}</a>
```

Comment: yes, I made an differnt approach: `<span @click.prevent="callNumber(entry[column.key])">` - then in the method it openend the calling window :-)

Answer (score 1):

you can simply use this way

```
<a href="tel:{entry[column.key]}" > {{entry[column.key]}} </a>
```

avoiding too much useless code (working and tested with nuxt3)